# how to add eigen to visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, include, eigen

I downloaded the folder from http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page and because Eigen doesn't get downloaded as a library but as a folder with code I don't know how to implement it to my code.

tried to include the folder which didn't work, also tried to include ".h" files and it didn't work either.

in the first case the include itself throw an error. in the second case the example code from the folder throw an error.

i would love if someone could help me with this. 
thanks.

Comment: "*... throw an error*" it definitely helped if you told us *which* errors you get. This is not a guessing game, is it?

Comment: Maybe you did not add the path to the headers correctly to your "Additional Include Directories". In either case saying it does not work will not help anyone solve the problem. We need exact error messages and to know exactly what you did.

Comment: What's this got to do with C?

Comment: See the Getting Started guide that they publish. Should solve all your problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look for Install or Readme files with these things.

The eigen Install file has three simple steps if you've installed CMake.

```
cd build_dir
cmake source_dir
make install
```

And it says `make install` will require root.